# Running .NET Core API project gives Error 502.5 - Process Failure

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .NET Core Web API project which all of a sudden stopped working correctly (on localhost) - when I run it on "AnyCPU" or "x86" platforms, I get this error:

> HTTP Error 502.5 - Process Failure

It only works when I run it in "x64".

I see that this question has been asked a lot, but mostly people had problems with deployment and I am running the project on localhost. Also, I didn't find a similar question with results depending on the platform.

Comment: When you say you "get" this error, do you mean in the browser? What do you see in the logs of ASP.NET Core (or the console of the process)?

Comment: It looks like you don't have the x86 version of the dotnet sdk installed.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this issue a few times. What resolved it for me was to ensure the target framework sdk is installed.

I was targeting 2.1.3 but only had 2.1.0 installed and failed for this reason.

If running on windows you can open the Event Viewer app and expand windows logs and select Application, the errors show up there and reveal more detailed error messages

Comment: Yep, I had same experience. Targeting right .NET Core resolves the problem.